# Java Swing- can't get things to display properly using Border Layout, also getting an illegal component position error

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I just wrote a simple code where I want a canvas to appear in the CENTER of a JFrame and a config panel to appear in the NORTH of the same JFrame.However after adding them both the 'canvas' doesn't get displayed at all.If I only add the canvas it does get displayed but as soon as I add the config panel it doesn't get displayed anymore.

Furthermore if I try to add something else in the SOUTH of the same JFrame I get a illegal component position error no matter what..

I'm a complete noob when it comes to Swing so sorry if  the answer is obvious but I tried googling and researching this for the last few hours without any luck.

Here's what I tried:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
 ConfigPanel configPanel;
 ControlPanel controlPanel;
 DrawingPanel canvas;

 public MainFrame() {
 super("My Drawing Application");
 init();
 }

private void init() {
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     canvas = new DrawingPanel(this);
     configPanel = new ConfigPanel(this);
     controlPanel=new ControlPanel(this);

      add(canvas,CENTER); 

      add(configPanel,NORTH);

      add(controlPanel,SOUTH); //this gives me a illegal component position error

     pack();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try `getContentPane().add(controlPanel, SOUTH);` instead of `add(controlPanel, SOUTH);`

do that for every component in the code you provided...

Comment: The add(…) method of the frame will add the component to the content pane for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
add(controlPanel,SOUTH);
```

All the lines should have errors. I'm not sure why that is the only one highlighted. The code should be:

```
add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

The preferred constraint is to use: `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Also, there is no reason to pass the frame to the panel in the constructor. If for some reason you need to know the frame of the panel you can invoke the `SwingUtiltites.windowForComponent(…)` method after the frame is visible.